# Puppeteer - Click button behind a notification

Tags: button, automation, notifications, puppeteer

Puppeteer 2.1.0
jest-puppeteer 4.4.0
Win 10 64bit

I have this situation https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDGBD.png

I want to click the green button but the notification is in my way.

My code:

```
selector = "//main/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]"
await page.waitForXPath(selector)
const elementHandle = await page.$x(selector)
await elementHandle[0].click()
```

This code won't click the button, and I know is the notification, because if before the click() I put a waitFor(5000) and close the notification manually then it works just fine

I also tried in the chrome console directly like this, and it works just fine with the notification in front

```
$x("//main/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]")[0].click()
```

Also this kind of code should work for headless mode, so the fact that the notification is "In front" should never be an issue.

Possible questions:

- Are you using headed mode? Yes, I have to. I'm testing using chrome extensions.
- Using Xpath instead of selectors? Yes, I have no option as well, I have to use xpath
- Why no closing the notification? It could work (and actually it does for this particular situation), but that's not the only notification that popUps, more of those show up and messes up with other similar buttons. I need to click the button behind the notification

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, I just changed the `await elementHandle[0].click()` for `await page.evaluate(x=>x.click() , elementHandle[0])`

I'll leave the question here, hope somebody find it useful